# Spring boot NXOpen library already loaded in other ClassLoader

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've been working with a project involving NX 9.0 and Spring boot. They way NX works is that you upload a JAR file and the NX executes it.

When I upload my JAR file everything goes well also I can call some test services I created and get my response back, the problem is when I call a service that uses the NXOpen library it throws the following exception:

*java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:NX9\libnxopenjavacore.dll already loaded in another classloader*

I was talking with some friends and they explain me that Spring boot has its own Classpath and NX also has/creates one, so when we try to use the library it said that the library has been already loaded, so I took off the NXOpen library from my Spring Boot jar but I still having the same error.

Hope you can help me!
Thanks!